# Erro com redirecionamento htaccess Sem para WWW

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Tenho o seguinte código no meu `htaccess` que faz o redirecionamento do usuário caso ele acesse o site sem www, funciona perfeitamente se você digitar o domínio direto sem www ele vai redirecionar, porém a partir do facebook ele não redireciona.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bluanime.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bluanime.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Da forma que está digitando `bluanime.com` na barra de endereços do navegador, ele é redirecionado para a versão `www.bluanime.com`, mas no facebook caso eu coloque na descrição só `bluanime.com` e a pessoa clique ele não é redirecionado, o que pode estar causando isso?

Esse é o link que deveria fazer o redirecionamento automático no facebook [Link para o redirecionamento](http://bluanime.com), até aqui no stack ele não é redirecionado para a versão www

Comment: O facebook obter os dados e gera o conteudo no box, mas isto não me parece uma falha do .htaccess e sim como o facebook funciona, ou seja o box não tem nada haver com redirecionar, se a pessoa clicar no link do então ao entrar em teu site o redirecionamento ocorre, mas não quer dizer que o facebook vai formatar o link pra ti.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Editei a pergunta e coloquei o link cujo redirecionamento deveria acontecer, até aqui no stack quando clica ele não é redirecionado

Comment: Aqui o link da postagem https://www.facebook.com/lparadoxu/posts/1911530899082005

Comment: Aqui se eu digito direto o link na barra sem www, ele faz o redirecionamento, o que há de errado então?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deve ser o cache do teu navegador que manteve o redirecionamento de algo, creio que ou o teu .htaccess não esteja na pasta ou seja outra falha, no caso isto não é necessário:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Faça assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bluanime.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bluanime.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Se falhar faça assim (esta forma na verdade eu creio que seja melhor porque será mais fácil portar se o domínio mudar ou usar múltiplos dominios):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Parece que agora funcionou e o link no facebook ta redirecionando, tanto aqui quanto no facebook, qual a importância das duas linhas que tu pediu pra eu remover nesse caso?

Comment: A duas linhas negavam o redirecionamento se o arquivo ou pasta existisse. @LeoLetto